# Notation for infinite-dimensional vector output of a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on an interval

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I want to create a vector of the "outputs" of the function, in the following sense: if $X$ was discrete, e.g., $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_K\}$, then I would write $F = \begin{pmatrix} f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_K) \end{pmatrix}$.

In actual fact, $X$ is the interval $[\underline{x}, \bar{x}]$. So I want the infinite-dimensional vector of the "outputs" of the function. I am tempted to write $F = \begin{pmatrix} f(\underline{x}) \\ \vdots \\ f(\bar{x}) \end{pmatrix}$, but this feels like an abuse of notation... is there a sensible way to write this?

Comment: What is the problem with writing $f(X)$? THe order of the components would be determines by the order on $X$.

Comment: THe function $f$ itself **is** the vector you seek. In typical vector notation $(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in\Bbb{R}^n$, we can think of this as the function $\alpha:\{1,\dots, n\}\to\Bbb{R}$, such that $\alpha(i)=a_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$; the notation $\Bbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as $\Bbb{R}^{\{1,\dots, n\}}$, the set of all functions from $\{1,\dots, n\}$ into $\Bbb{R}$. So, likewise $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$ would be a vector in the function space $\Bbb{R}^X$. Another common notation is by indexing: $F=(f(x))_{x\in X}$, but this is unnecessary as the symbol $f$ conveys the same information

Comment: @Jay thanks! I would think of $f(X)$ as the image of $X$ under $f$, i.e., the set of outputs, rather than the vector output — but are you saying that $f(X)$ can alternatively denote the vector output?

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks, that is very helpful! (Was going to ask a follow-up question, but the edit you made just now clarifies it perfectly!)

Comment: If you want to do something like this, define exactly what you are doing. If you are using $f(X)$ to denote the image of $X$ under $f$, Write something like $f[X]$ or use some other type of bracket symbol.

Comment: You could say $f|_{[0,1]}$, or $f|_{[1,2]}$, or $(f|_{[0,1]}, f|_{[1,2]})$ depending on what you mean.